# how to use <input/> in xhml using JSF of java?

Tags: jsf

i want to know how to use 
     
of HTML in xhtml page using jsf framework. or please suggest me how to use bootstrap in jsf framework. i tried to use jsf tags instead of HTML tags 
but the bootstrap theme and css are not loading properly. can anybody suggest me how to use bootstrap in jsf or any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As per [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp) :

> XHTML Elements

1. XHTML elements must be properly nested
2. **XHTML elements must always be closed**
3. XHTML elements must be in lowercase
4. XHTML documents must have one root element

Related to your problem, Bootstrap can be used with JSF with no problem. Just simply include *.css* and *.js* provided by Bootstrap and use them normally in *XHTML* files as you would do in *HTML*, but taking care of the above restrictions.